# @blur in v-autocomplete vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a v-autocomplete that I need to call a function @blur but it doesn't work like with v-select or
v-text-field is there something different that I have to do?

```
           <v-autocomplete
            v-model="selectedItems"
            @blur="test"
            :items="items"
            solo
            flat
            chips
            small-chips
            multiple
          ></v-autocomplete>

          <v-select
            v-model="selectedItems"
            @blur="test"
            :items="items"
            solo
            flat
            chips
            small-chips
            multiple
          ></v-select>
```

Script:

```
    methods : {
         test(){ console.log("test")}
    }
```

Why does the v-autocomplete do not console.log but the v-select do?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem relative to vuetify . Which vuetify version are you using : 2.1.x ?
If so , you should upgrade vuetify in 2.2.x

Comment: thank you I will make sure I have the most current version.